# How To Implement Responsive Grid Ui in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am facing problem during creating following UI: 
[image]

How can I implement this kind of design?

Comment: Have you looked at the great set of examples available on the Bootstrap site? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cwVm4/ Sorry forgot to add fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 3 is "mobile-first", start with your desired layout for the smallest device ("screen 4") using the `xs` classes, and then go up from there.

Here is an example to get you started: http://bootply.com/129266

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive tables with the grid system. Here I did Screen #1 for you:

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <tr >
   <td class="col-md-4" rowspan="2" style="background-color:red">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="col-md-2" style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="col-md-2" style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="col-md-2" style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td class="col-md-2" style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   <td style="background-color:blue">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
```

NOTE the classes in the td tag col-md-4 and col-md-2. Using the grid system they must add up to 12. Using a larger number allocates more space to that column. Adjust the table width as necessary.